# Simple MySQL query in a relatively large table runs very slow

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-performance

I have a database table with zipcodes, timezones, latitude, longitude and some other location data covering the entire world. There are 8,379,070 rows in the table. Over half of GB of data, probably. The table is called `timezones`.

When I try to run a query to get all records that have a postcode of "90210" like this:

`select * from timezones where postcode = 90210;`

the query returns `28` rows, but only after `7.73` seconds.

I tried adding an auto-incrementing primary key integer field, and indexing the table by postcode field, but nothing helps.

At this speed, the table will not be usable. It was supposed to be used for retrieving suggestions for an auto-complete zipcode field in a form on a website.

Is there any way I could make this run faster?

---

This is my table description:

`+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| country   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region1   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region2   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region3   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| locality  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode  | varchar(45) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| latitude  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timezone  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| utc       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dst       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idx       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: @Mihai you mean columns (28 rows returned)

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you have an index on postcode or not.

Comment: I`m blind@James.If there really is an index  on postcode it should run a lot faster even with 8 million rows at that data distirbution.Can you show the table definition?

Comment: Try to update statistics `ANALYZE TABLE timezones ;`It will lock the table,be careful

Comment: @Mihai I ran that, got status ok `1 row in set (0.04 sec)`

Comment: So you really need all the columns?

Comment: @Mihai in most cases, yes.

Comment: Why is the PostCode column a varchar type and not an int type? Using an int will speed up the performance with an index.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne In some countries, the postcode contains letters.

Comment: What if you store the postal code (hashed) as a hashcode in an extra column of int type...build an index on that. When you perform your select you hash the passed postalcode and search on the index hashcolumn...

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN select * from timezones where postcode = 90210;` and show us result, it will tell if it is using index or not.

Comment: Careful!  if you run the same exact query more than once MySQL helpfully returns the result from its cache, very quickly. This can be confusing. Try `SELECT QUERY_NO_CACHE * FROM timezones WHERE postcode='90210'`  while you're sorting out this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the index on `postcode`:

```
create index idx_timezones_postcode on timezones(postcode);
```

Then, be sure that your types are correct when you write the query:

```
select tz.*
from timezones tz
where tz.postcode = '90210';
```

Type conversion can prevent the use of the index.